# Ajax validation callout extender with Behaviour ID validation

Tags: ajax, validation

I have defined Ajaxvalidatoncalloutextender control with unique behaviour ID in my page for all the page controls.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceNotProgress" runat="server" TargetControlID="revInvalidNotClosedProgressValue" BehaviorID="b_vceNotProgress">
                        </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceProgress" runat="server" TargetControlID="revInvalidClosedProgressValue" BehaviorID="b_vceProgress">
                        </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

I'm validating on client click of submit button like this

```
function ValidatePage() 
                        {
                            if (typeof (Page_Validators) == "undefined") return;
                            var noOfValidators = Page_Validators.length;
                            var Page_Callout = new Array(2);
                            Page_Callout[0] = "b_vceNotProgress"; -- behaviour ID
                            Page_Callout[1] = "b_vceProgress"; -- behaviour ID
                            for (var validatorIndex = 0; validatorIndex < noOfValidators; validatorIndex++) {
                                var validator = Page_Validators[validatorIndex];
                                ValidatorValidate(validator);
                                if (!validator.isvalid) {
                                    showValidatorCallout($find(Page_Callout[validatorIndex]));
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
```

My Problem: I donot want to hardcode the array like Page_Callout[0],Page_Callout[1]. I need to populate the array based 
                            on the visible controls (i.e assign behaviour ID) in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (typeof (Page_Validators) == "undefined") return;

        var noOfValidators = Page_Validators.length;
        var count = 0;
        var Page_Callout = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            Page_Callout[Page_Callout.length++] = Page_Validators[i]._behaviors != null ? Page_Validators[i]._behaviors[0]._id : "";
            count++;
        }

        for (var validatorIndex = 0; validatorIndex < noOfValidators; validatorIndex++) {
            var validator = Page_Validators[validatorIndex];

            ValidatorValidate(validator);

            if (!validator.isvalid) {
                showValidatorCallout($find(Page_Callout[validatorIndex]));
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function hideValidatorCallout() {
        AjaxControlToolkit.ValidatorCalloutBehavior._currentCallout.hide();
    }

    function showValidatorCallout(currrentCallout) {
        AjaxControlToolkit.ValidatorCalloutBehavior._currentCallout = currrentCallout;
        AjaxControlToolkit.ValidatorCalloutBehavior._currentCallout.show(true);
    }
```